# ある数を各要素1byteずつのリストに変換したい

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

こんにちは，

今，1.「ある数を定義すると」2.「あとはその数をIEEE754表現に直して(4byte)」3.「それを1byteずつの要素のリストにしてくれる」プログラムを書いています．ほとんど出来ているのですが，どうにも最後の工程のスマートなやり方がわかりません．ぜひ教えていただきたいです，

１．「ある数を定義すると」は例としてpiを採用します

```
pi=3.141592
```

２．「あとはその数をIEEE754表現に直して(4byte)」についてはstructを使います，リトルエンディアンにしてます．

```
import struct
buff=struct.pack(“<f”,pi) 
print( buff.hex()) #d80f4940
```

3.「それを1byteずつの要素のリストにしてくれる」最後ここがわかりません．

目標は `bytes=[  0xd8, 0x0f, 0x49, 0x40     ]` あるいは `bytes=[  216, 15, 73, 64     ]`のようなものを自動で生成することなのですが,これをやろうとするとどうにも回りくどくなってしまって…(strを分けて，0xをくっつけて...のように）

ただ，数のリストが帰って来れば良いです．何かシンプルな方法はありませんか？

Comment: `print(f'type: {type(buff)}\t list: {list(buff)}')`
あと 一般的に通信でバイナリデータ送るのなら, 通常ネットワークオーダーにします。`'>f'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

すでに1byteずつ扱えます

```
import struct
pi=3.141592
buff=struct.pack("<f", pi) 
print( buff[0]) #216
print( buff[1]) #15
print( buff[2]) #73
print( buff[3]) #64
```

`list`にしたいならば

```
print(list(buff)) # [216, 15, 73, 64]
```

Comment: なんと！お恥ずかしい！>< ありがとうございます！